# stack level too deep (when changing model inheritance)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-table-inheritance

I'm trying to use the [citier gem](https://github.com/PeterHamilton/citier) to convert some models that already exist in the following way. So far this works:

Created models:

```
Attachable < ActiveRecord::Base
Link < Attachable
```

I added `acts_as_citier` to both models, created and ran the migrations with no problem. Database views are created as well. Now if I try to do this to an existing model:

Before:

```
SpecialLink < ActiveRecord::Base
```

After:

```
SpecialLink < Link
```

and then I try to run any command like `rails g migration` or `rails console`, I get:

`script/rails:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me a whole lot beyond a suspicion that I have an infinite loop somewhere. Does anyone know what might be causing this? Or have an idea of where I can look or get more information about the issue? It would not be a good solution for me to have to create the models again from scratch to work with citier...

Comment: Yes, unless there's a full stacktrace, it's tough to figure out what's going on. Does this exception also occur for rake tasks (eg rake db:migrate)?
I which case you can pass: "rake db:migrate --trace" and get a full stacktrace. Not sure if you can pass that for console/etc